# open Url in android in web browser application

Tags: android, android-webview, intentfilter

I am working on a Web browser. The web browser is working, but I need help in the part where my Application catches Android system's url when clicked (http,https etc) and open my web browser application

Like any other browser chrome ,firefox etc, how these app open the default app choose menu?

Reading about these I learn about `<intent-filter>` is used

Can someone help me with what to be added to Manifest file and to my activity so that my Application catches url?

Comment: What have you tried or researched about [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [CATEGORY_BROWSABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT) to your activity that can handle URLs.

Like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<!--This makes activity an option for the default action (center press) to perform 
on a piece of data. -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

<!-- Activities that can be safely invoked from a browser must support this category. -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```